# Delphi 2010 DCPCrypt2 Sha256 Hash doesn't equal PHP Hash

Tags: php, delphi, hash, delphi-2010, sha256

I'm writing a Delphi 2010 application that will connect to the PHP Web application to get specific data. Web page on the server accepts 3 **GET** parameters:

1. cityid   // Value needed for web application to return specific data
2. salt     // Current time stamp: Year Month Date Hour Minute Second Millisecond
3. token    // SHA-256 hash with security key for protection

The problem is with **token**. It's generated in Delphi using these functions:

```
function DigestToStr(Digest: array of byte): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to Length(Digest) do
    Result := Result + LowerCase(IntToHex(Digest[i], 2));
end;

function GetStringHash(Source: string): string;
var
  Hash: TDCP_sha256;
  Digest: array[0..31] of Byte;
begin
  Hash := TDCP_sha256.Create(nil);
  Hash.Init;
  Hash.UpdateStr(Source);
  Hash.Final(Digest);
  Hash.Free;
  Result := DigestToStr(Digest);
end;

procedure TMain.Button3Click(Sendere: TObject);
var
  TheToken,Sha256:string;
begin
  salt:=FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnsszzz',Now);
  TheToken:=salt+'THE_SECRET_KEY'+MCity;
  Sha256:=GetStringHash(TheToken);
end;
```

Delphi gives this string for a **token**: **ec4338bb3e7819a1148ffc01713f6d164f4f5940c5758d896b0a3d53f30f8c24f0**

PHP's **hash** function gives totally different string:

```
<?php
  hash('sha256','20120119115458592THE_SECRET_KEY1');
?>
```

**8b4cff3b937bbcfae8fa7a67ce407b6185451a52e994ea2ef92a760676717490**

I tried to look for similar questions on the Web, but found only symmetric encryption/description problems discussed, I don't need symmetric encryption for the **token**

---

**UPDATE**
I've figured out!!! The problem was in the wrong variable type!

I used **string**, and when I replaced it with **AnsiString** it worked out!

```
function GetStringHash(Source: AnsiString): string;
var
  ...
```

Besides that I replaced

```
  for i := 0 to Length(Digest) do
```

with

```
  for i := 0 to Length(Digest)-1 do
```

in **DigestToStr** function

Sorry for causing disturbance, but I hope this will help somebody!

Comment: Can you check your Delphi implementation against [the example strings on the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Examples_of_SHA-2_variants)?  In particular, `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` should hash to `d7a8fbb307d7809469ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb762d02d0bf37c9e592`.  I expect it won't, given that PHP seems to be operating correctly here for the given string and resulting hash...

Comment: Yes you are right... It gives me: 3b5b0eac46c8f0c16fa1b9c187abc8379cc936f6508892969d49234c6c540e58f0

Comment: This question was helpful for me, thanks.